# Given two independent random variables, calculate $P(X^2 > Y)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

$X$ and $Y$ are distributed identically, with probability density function:

\begin{equation}
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      2x, & \text{if}\ 0 < x <1 \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

And cumulative distribution function:

\begin{equation}
    F(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ x \leq 0 \\
      x^2, & \text{if}\ x \in ]0,1[ \\
      1, & \text{if}\ x \geq 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Upon looking at the answer, it is of the form of a double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x^2} (2x)(2y) dydx=\frac{1}{3}$$

Performing the integration is not the issue, it's how to get there, to be honest. I am not sure what property of the independent random variables allows us to solve it in this way. Is it something to do with the fact that:

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X(x) \cdot F_Y(y)$$

I saw additionally [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396386/finding-an-expression-for-the-probability-that-one-random-variable-is-less-than), which shows the same kind of formula. I can't find it anywhere in my probability textbook, so assume it is derived from another one of the properties we have been given, but I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The independence of $X$ and $Y$ gives you the *joint density*: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f(x)f(y).$$

Once you have the joint density,
$$
P(X^2>Y)=\iint_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2>y\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dxdy\\
=\iint_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2>y\}}f(x)f(y)\ dxdy.
$$

Now, it is an exercise to show (using the definition of $f$) that
$$
\iint_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2>y\}}f(x)f(y)\ dxdy=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x^2} (2x)(2y) dydx.
$$

Comment: I think I understand! Regarding the final exercise, is this correct?:

$P(X^2 > Y) = P(Y \leq X^2)=P(X^2 < \infty, Y\leq X^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x^2}f_Y(y) \cdot f_X(x)dydx$ And then upon limiting only to the support we get $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2}f_Y(y) \cdot f_X(x)dydx$

Comment: Or one can directly do the double integral on $\{(x,y)|x^2>y\}\cap[0,1]\times[0,1]$ without referring to the event $X^2<\infty$.

Comment: The way that I wrote makes more sense in my head, so if it's correct I think I'll keep to that. Thanks for your help :)